# Application Migration from Red Hat Open Shift cluster to Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, web-applications, migration, openshift, azure-aks

I have straight forward use case in which I have to migrate an web application running on redhat openshift cluster which needs to be migrated to Azure kubernetes Service.

I have experience working with AKS but not with Openshift cluster.

Can you guys give me any feedback on this, I am not sure of what I should be considering for this migration & there is no online resource I could find to study on it.

Please share your thoughts on this use case regarding any prerequisites that are required for this migration or anything else I should consider for this migration any resource would be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you currently using kubernetes primitives for deploying your application on openshift? if so migration should be fairly easy. If it is currently using openshift specific resources, e.g. buildconfigs, deploymentconfigs, routes you will need to migrate those as they are not provided by AKS

Comment: Currently application is deployed on-prem on open shift cluster & its using open shift specific resources. I am looking for  a detailed guide if there is any on this topic please share.

Comment: then you will need to migrate openshift specific resources to vanilla kubernetes ones. 
DeploymentConfig --> Deployment.  Routes --> svc + ingress + ingress controller. templates --> helm chart. maybe changes for image registries and imagestreams are required as well. BuildConfig --> tekton/jenkins/other cicd infrastructure

Comment: @Sarmad- I am in same boat as you - if you have since made any progress, can you pls share your findinga for this migration path? Sincerely appreciate your help & support. tc

Comment: @DeepakChaudhary Yes, actually I could not find any path or resource to do that, you can read meaningqo comment because that is the approach to it. We converted Redhad resources to AKs resources for example we wrote deployment files etc which were similar to how Redhat cluster was configured. Also image was being pushed to private registry and CI/CD pipelines are being use to do the deployments. I hope this helps.